# Copy specific files from folder listed in a text file

Tags: shell-script

I have a list of folder names in .txt file. I want the code to pick a name from text file, match in a directory, enter that folder and a subfolder and copy a file and paste it to another directory and also add folder name in front of the file name.

For an example I have folder name A, B, C and they have sub-folder name X, Y, Z respectively. I want the code to enter A folder and then sub-folder X and then copy a file name '1' and paste it another folder and also add folder name to file i.e., 'A1'
I'm using the following code but its not working

```
for i in CC110033; do cp /dataslave2/shyamchand/aamod_meg_maxfilt_00001/$i/rest/transdef_mf2pt2_rest_raw.fif /cblhome/vivek/Data/MEG_data_80sub/transdef_mf2pt2_rest_raw.fif; done
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your input file to the question, rather than explaining it?

Comment: @Kusalananda I tried writing another code, may be you get better idea with it.  {for i in CC110033 CC110037 do
  cp /dataslave2/shyamchand/aamod_meg_maxfilt_00001/$i/rest/transdef_mf2pt2_rest_raw.fif /cblhome/vivek/Data/MEG_data_80sub/$i_transdef_mf2pt2_rest_raw.fif
done}

Comment: Clarifications to the question should be added to the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this I am assuming that CC110033 is the text file.

By using `for i in CC110033` is pointless. The only thing you will get is a variable named $i which content is CC110033. You should choose a different loop structure. Like `while read i; do .... done < CC110033`